# Как можно отправить Javascript результаты на MySql сервер?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Как можно отправить Javascript результаты на MySql сервер?

Например

Свойство `navigator.language` возвращает язык браузера

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(navigator.language);
</script>
```

Дает нам такой значение

> ru

и как можно отправить на MySql как `ru` не `<script type="text/javascript">document.write(navigator.language);</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете ajax запрос, в параметрах которых есть язык браузера. Соответственно, скрипт на php его обрабатывает (он же и подключается к mysql).

Comment: Спасибо я понимаю но не могу реализовать помогите если вы знаете

Comment: За вас тут писать никто не будет. Не советую на это рассчитывать. А вот ссылками могу поделиться. [Ajax jQuery](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-запрос), а [вот совместная работа](http://dontforget.pro/javascript/primer-ajax-otpravki-formyi-na-email-s-pomoshhyu-jquery-i-php/) с php

Comment: Спасибо за помочь!!!